# Encode the user ID into a 32 character hash in PHP, be able to read/decode it when passed back?

Tags: php

I am curious what's the most elegant way (or even just suggested ways, industry standards, etc) of encoding a user ID (which is a 3-4 digit number) into a 32 character (letters and numbers only) hash that the user can use to pass back into the script that is able to decode that and get the original user ID from it?

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by definition, that would not be a hash, as a hash is one way. i use both for users and other ids, they all have a simple id, and a hash stored in the db, the hash for external uses, the id for internal

Comment: Like @Dagon mentioned, you cannot decode hashes. You can match hashes, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a hashing algorithm which generates a fixed length hash string despite the length of the input string, then you can't decode it back. If you want to be able to decode back, then use something like base64, but you won't have always the same length of the encoded string.

Comment: is there any way to encode it into a fixed length string of custom length?

Comment: With the posibility of decoding it back, no. Imagine that you have a file of 10MB and you encode it to a fixed 32 bytes string. You won't be able to get back those 10MB of data from a 32 byte string.